# ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to service config

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I try to run the `gcloud endpoints` command and I got errors:

```
    gcloud endpoints services deploy \
        msh-common-proto/release/api_descriptor.pb \
        .deploy/api_config.yaml \
        --no-user-output-enabled
```

errors:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to service config.
 'location: "unknown location"
kind: ERROR
message: "Unresolved type \'.google.protobuf.Timestamp\'"

 location: "unknown location"
kind: ERROR
message: "Unresolved type \'.google.protobuf.Timestamp\'"

 location: "unknown location"
kind: ERROR
message: "Unresolved type \'.google.protobuf.Timestamp\'"
...
```

I didn't change my code, the only thing I did is update gcloud cli tools and buf tool.

After I got these errors, I decide to update all my python Google packages but I still have the same error.

Does anyone have an idea?

My versions:

```
GCLOUD
Google Cloud SDK 468.0.0
alpha 2024.03.08
beta 2024.03.08
bq 2.0.101
cloud-build-local 0.5.2
core 2024.03.08
gsutil 5.27

Python 3.11.7
protobuf==4.24.4

macOS version 12.6.7
```

Comment: Current version of the gcloud SDK is 470, could be that this is already fixed

Comment: No unfortunately.. I get the same error message.

Comment: Is it possible that your `api_descriptor.pb` has changed and now imports `google.protobuf.Timestamp`? The error you show could result from this change and without using `protoc --include_imports` when you compile your protobuf sources into the descriptor.

Comment: I finally found the problem but updating protoc, it was the only one I forgot to update.